# Connecting to wifi after remove wificonfiguration and reboot android device

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I'm working on an app, with which you can connect to different wifinetworks and remove all configured wifinetworks on the device.

I can connect to a wifi network and delete the wifi network. But there is a strange behavior when reboot the device. There is no other configured (saved) wifi network on the android device. But after a reboot the android device connect to a wifi network. I know that there is a change in Wifi and Networking since Android M (Version 6). Your app can only change the state of Wificonfigurtion Objects only if you created these objects. So before I tested the app I removed all configured Wifi Networks manually.

Can someone explain me this behavior? I appreciate your help.

Here is the code to remove the configured networks manually

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                List<WifiConfiguration> list =  wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
                for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {

                    wifiManager.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
                }
```

I expect that when I remove all configured wifi networks, after a reboot of the device, there are no configured wifi networks and the device is not connecting to a wifi network automatically.

Actually when I remove all wifi networks through my app and reboot the device, the device establishes a wifi connection automatically although there is no configured wifi network before reboot.